# Best Scheduler for .NET Application?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to determine what would be a good Process Scheduler for .NET applications, so far I have only looked into Quartz.NET. Are there any viable alternatives and what are the tradeoffs when using them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Honestly, Quartz.NET is pretty much the best one out there.  One of Quartz.NET's biggest strengths lies in the fact that you schedule tasks using [CRON expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples).  This gives you are succinct format that can easily be configured and stored in a variety of places.

Comment: +1 - agree, and have been using it for a while now.  We store the jobs, tasks and schedules in the database, makes for super easy task scheduling that users can manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider Windows Task Scheduler, there are couple of limitations such as Windows XP Home Edition but other than it should do fine for basic tasks.